# Updating variables in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

#### My Goal

I want to remove all the `1` values from the `items` property (2d array) [shown in this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/wabebituvi/edit?html,console,output) by pressing the *Clear* button.

#### Steps to recreate the problem

1. Open this jsBin.
2. In the output pane, press the *Show* button.
3. Look in the console, notice the logged output:

   `"Items: Lorem,Ipsum,foo,1,bar,1,baz,0,qux,0"`
4. In the output pane, press the *Clear* button.
5. Look in the console, notice the logged output is the same as before:

   `"Items: Lorem,Ipsum,foo,1,bar,1,baz,0,qux,0"`

#### What I expect to see...

In the last step described above, in the console, I expect to see the following logged to the console:

```
Lorem,Ipsum,foo,0,bar,0,baz,0,qux,0
```

#### What I actually see...

Instead, as already described, I see:

```
Lorem,Ipsum,foo,1,bar,1,baz,0,qux,0
```

Note the lack of agreement between the HTML rendered on the screen and the logged value [is addressed by this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35172641/1640892). (This question is not a duplicate for reasons described below.)

## Question

> How do I successfully update the value of the `items` variable to:
>
> `[['Lorem','Ipsum'],['foo',0],['bar',0],['baz',0],['qux',0]]`?

(Please show a working jsBin if possible.)

#### Code

http://jsbin.com/wabebituvi/edit?html,console,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <button on-tap="_show">Show</button>
  <button on-tap="clearAll">Clear</button>
  <div>{{selected}}</div>
  <div>{{items}}</div>
</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-element',
      properties: {
        items: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          computed: '_computeItems(selected)',
          value: function() {
            return [['Lorem', 'Ipsum'], ['foo', 0], ['bar', 0], ['baz', 0], ['qux', 0],];
          }
        },
        selected: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          value: [],
        },
      },
      _computeItems: function(a) {
        var out = this.items,
            selectedLength = a.length,
            i = out.length;
        while(i---1){
          var j = selectedLength;
          while(j--) {
            if(a.indexOf(out[i][0])===-1){
              out[i][1] = 0;
            }
            else if(a.indexOf(out[i][0])>-1){
              out[i][1] = 1;
            }
            else {
              console.log('Error: Undefined index of selected item');
            }
          }
        }
        return out;
      },
      _computeSelected: function(a) {
        var out = [],
            i = a.length;
        while(i---1){
          if(a[i][1]){out.push(a[i][0]);}
        }
        return out.sort();
      },
      ready: function(){
        this.set('items', this._computeItems(this.seletcted));
      },
      clearAll: function() {
        this.set('selected', []);
        this.set('items', this._computeItems(this.selected));
      },
      _show: function() {
        console.log('Selected: ' + this.selected);
        console.log('Items: ' + this.items);
      },
    });
  })();

</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element
  selected='["foo","bar"]'
></x-element>

</body>
```

Reasons why this question is not a duplicate:
The code is similar, but not the same. And the questions are also similar but different. The solutions, I suspect, are probably related and might be the result of whatever I'm not understanding. The alternative: Asking both questions in a single post, I fear would be too complicated to receive effective answers. So I am opting to try to separate the issues into separate questions to help others understand and provide clearer answers. And finally, this is my attempt to provide a minimal example. I've trimmed out a lot of code

Comment: Looks like the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172641/databinding-in-polymer. Please update the first question instead of creating a new one. And please reduce the code to a **minimal** example.

Comment: I noted the question you reference in the body of this question. The code is similar, but not the same. And the questions are also similar but different. The solutions, I suspect, are probably related and might be the result of whatever I'm not understanding. The alternative: Asking both questions in a single post, I fear would be too complicated to receive effective answers. So I am opting to try to separate the issues into separate questions to help others understand and provide clearer answers. And finally, this is my attempt to provide a minimal example. I've trimmed out a lot of code.

Comment: I assume if one question is answered the answer to the other will become obvious.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I agree that's a highly likely scenario. Whoever answers will get double points!

Comment: @Mowzer there're a bunch of errors in the console when I open your jsbin. Is that normal?

Comment: @zerodevx: I suspect it's okay because everything is loading and not everything is defined when being referenced from other places.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your jsbin gives me an error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot set property items of #<x-element> which has only a getter
```

and I had to comment out:

```
this.set('items', this._computeItems(this.selected));
```

to stop it.

From what I see, your _computeSelected function never clears, because after setting selected to [], selectedLength is equal 0 and your inner loop never evaluates.

I've added some code to reset those counters to 0 before entering the while loops and it seems to work:

```
_computeItems: function(a) {
    var out = this.items,
        selectedLength = a.length,
        i = out.length;
    out.forEach(function(pair) {
      if (Number.isInteger(pair[1])) {
        pair[1] = 0;
      }
    });
    while(i---1){
      var j = selectedLength;
      while(j--) {
        if(a.indexOf(out[i][0])===-1){
          out[i][1] = 0;
        }
        else if(a.indexOf(out[i][0])>-1){
          out[i][1] = 1;
        }
        else {
          console.log('Error: Undefined index of selected item');
        }
      }
    }
    return out;
  },
```

Console output:

```
"Selected: foo,bar"
"Items: Lorem,Ipsum,foo,1,bar,1,baz,0,qux,0"
"Selected: "
"Items: Lorem,Ipsum,foo,0,bar,0,baz,0,qux,0"
```